# Huge gap between local and remote Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have installed two instances of Cassandra. One on my localhost and an other on a remote server.

Throught the DevCenter, when I try to insert 579 (short) statements, I get the following results :

on localhost : 579 statement(s) successfuly executed in 460 ms

on remote host : 579 statement(s) successfuly executed in 87829 ms

Any help would be appreciate...

Comment: it will depend on where your remote server is located..
and you always find the difference between this two.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers sound like the statements are being executed synchronously with a single thread.

Cassandra can overcome latency by having multiple statements in flight at once, but if the application only uses a single thread and waits for each statement to finish before issuing the next one, then it will incur the round trip delay for each statement.

If you divide 87829 by 579 you get 151 ms per statement, so you could check the ping time to the remote server and see if it is about about 150 ms.

So to insert faster you would use an application that uses a thread pool and issues many inserts in parallel asynchronously.  This can give a throughput similar to what you get on the low ping localhost.